# Qt/C++ Connect to Classic Bluetooth device

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth

I am trying to pair and connect a bluetooth speaker to my device in Qt. Qt offers with `QBluetoothLocalDevice` the functionality I need for pairing, which works fine for my purpose. But I can not find a method to connect to the speaker after it has been paired.

I need to connect to it so when calling `pactl list sinks` I see the sink I need for playback. The class `QBluetoothLocalDevice` offers signals for deviceConnected and disconnected but it does not have a connection method. I would be optimal to have the connection be still alive after the destruction of the pointer to QBluetoothLocalDevice.

Anybody know to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to programmatically do that in QT at the moment.

You are going to have to use [DBus API](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc) to send a connection request to Bluez.

As a simple workaround, you can run bluetoothctl if it is installed in your system:

```
QProcess process;
process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::SeparateChannels);
process.start("bluetoothctl");
process.waitForStarted();
process.write(QString("connect %1\n").arg(address).toUtf8());
process.closeWriteChannel();
process.waitForFinished();
```

Comment: thats what I am doing right now. Thanks you nethertheless. Guess QT developers havent thought of people wanting to connect to a device...